# PyMysql UPDATE query

Tags: python, mysql, sql-update, pymysql

I've been trying using PyMysql and so far everything i did worked (Select/insert) but when i try to update it just doesn't work, no errors no nothing, just doesn't do anything.

```
import pymysql
connection = pymysql.connect(...)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("UPDATE Users SET IsConnected='1' WHERE Username='test'")
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

and yes I've double checked that Users, IsConnected and Username are all correct and test does exist (SELECT works on it)

what's my problem here?

Comment: I suspect pymysql is automatically starting a transaction which you are not explicitly committing, so its rolling back when you close the connection.

Comment: So what should i do to fix it? remove the cursor.close()
connection.close()?

Comment: try a call to `connection.commit()` after your call to `cursor.execute()`

Comment: It worked! but can you try to explain to me what .commit() exactly does so I can understand what went wrong?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When you execute your update, MySQL is implicitly starting a transaction.  You need to commit this transaction by calling `connection.commit()` after you execute your update to keep the transaction from automatically rolling back when you disconnect.

MySQL (at least when using the InnoDB engine for tables) supports [transactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction), which allow you to run a series of update/insert statements then have them either all commit at once effectively as a single operation, or rollback so that none are applied.  If you do not explicitly commit a transaction, it will rollback automatically when you close your connection to the database.

Answer (score 24):

In fact, what @JoeDay has described above has little to do with default MySQL transaction's behaviour. MySQL by default operates in [auto-commit mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html) and normally you don't need any additional twist to persist your changes:

> By default, MySQL runs with autocommit mode enabled. This means that as soon as you execute a statement that updates (modifies) a table, MySQL stores the update on disk to make it permanent. The change cannot be rolled back.

PEP-249's (DB API) authors decided to complicate things and break Zen of Python by making a transaction's start implicit, by proposing auto-commit to be disabled by default.

What I suggest to do, is to restore MySQL's default behaviour. And use transactions explicitly, only when you need them.

```
import pymysql

connection = pymysql.connect(autocommit=True)
```

I've also written about it [here](https://mysqlsimplequerybuilder.readthedocs.org/en/latest/design.html#autocommit) with a few references.

Comment: This is the best answer!

Comment: Turning on autocommit can significantly decrease the performance of transactions. Not in the author's simple case, though.

Comment: @ZuOverture Autocommit has nothing to do with *performance of transactions* as such. You, as a developer, control granularity and isolation of transactions which directly affects their performance.

Comment: @saaj, I wasn't talking about performance of their intrinsics, obviously. Autocommit is not off by default in pymysql for no reason, it encourages learning how to organize transactions to avoid excessive autocommit overhead.

Comment: The answer as always is: it depends. Explicit commits are needed in Oracle and they change performance in a very noticeable way. In MySQL the difference is negligible and they just over complicate things. In case of doubt, always measure!